# How to draw pairs in yed graph editor?

Tags: yed

I want to have simple diagrams about analogies. I have two groups, both groups contain things like A,B,C, so for example group 1's A thing is A1, whole group 2's A thing is A2. I connected A1 and A2 with an edge just like B1 with B2 and C1 with C2. I want a very simple diagram, something like a table with the things connected. It should be completely symmetrical. Now every layout I choose goes totally insane and puts things very far from each other. It gets even worse, when I connect A1, B1 and C1 to describe relationships and I need the same layout for A2, B2 and C2 to show similarity. I have no idea what settings to choose, but for now all I could do is doing it manually. Idk. why this tool is such useless for this kind of jobs. I tried all layouts for 2-3 hours and nothing helped. Any idea?

[image]

[image]

Settings:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BFS layering solved it. You can change it in hierarchic layout settings / layers / layer assignment policy.